# how does the great framework, like spring, rails, to test the code itself

Tags: java

There are so many great framework, like spring, rails. And they release frequently. How do they ensure the quality of each release? How to test the framework itself?

Comment: What makes you think a framework is any different from any other large project?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework provides support for integration testing in the spring-test module. The library includes the org.springframework.test package, which contains valuable classes for integration testing with a Spring container. This testing does not rely on an application server or other deployment environment. Such tests are slower to run than unit tests but much faster than the equivalent Selenium tests or remote tests that rely on deployment to an application server.

In Spring 2.5 and later, unit and integration testing support is provided in the form of the annotation-driven Spring TestContext Framework. The TestContext framework is agnostic of the actual testing framework in use, thus allowing instrumentation of tests in various environments including JUnit, TestNG, and so on.

The org.springframework.test.web package contains ModelAndViewAssert, which you can use in combination with JUnit, TestNG, or any other testing framework for unit tests dealing with Spring MVC objects.